# How to resize user prompt so a box appears rather than a row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dialog

I'm using the ui.prompt() to get user input for the rest of my apps script to work. However, I'd like it if the space where the user enters their response were larger, so should they have to type a considerate amount (4-5 sentences), the entire text is visible rather than having to mouse over to the beginning/end of the input.

I'm not sure if there's a function which allows me to set a custom size (height and width, or variable such as a "drag the corner" of the text window) for the input section.

```
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var bodyresponse = ui.prompt(

  "The default email template is: " + 

  "\n\nIf you have any questions regarding your order, please email us directly by replying." +
  "\n\nIf you would like to update your contact information, billing/shipping address, " + 
  "or have an adjustment to make on the Purchase Order attached to this email, " +
  "please reach out to us within 7 days of receiving this Purchase Order." + 
  "\n\nThank you from Area Code 407!" +

  "\n\nWould you like to include an accompanying note? If so, include it below: \n\n\n\n ", 

  ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0nL6.png)

Comment: What you are looking for is called a [custom dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs) as detailed in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the *prompt* functionality will not let you do this. You can, however, achieve what you want by making a [Dialog box](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface-title). Then, using [client-to-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) you can pass the information back to your server-side script.

This is not a perfect example but the general idea of what needs to be done.

Code.gs

```
var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlFromFile('Dialog')
    .setWidth(250)
    .setHeight(300);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'My Title');

function dialogData(userNote){
   //Do something with userNote...
}
```

Dialog.html

```html
<body>
  Hello, world!
  <p> The default email template is: </p>

  <p>If you have any questions regarding your order, please email us directly by replying. If you would like to update your contact information, billing/shipping address, or have an adjustment to make on the Purchase Order attached to this email, please
    reach out to us within 7 days of receiving this Purchase Order.</p>
  <p>Thank you from Area Code 407! </p>

  <p>Would you like to include an accompanying note? If so, include it below: </p>
  <textarea id="userNote" rows="4" cols="80"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="returnData()" />
  <script>
    function returnData() {
      var note = document.getElementById("userNote").value
      console.log(note);
      google.script.run.onSuccessHandler(closeMe).dialogData(); //This calls a script in your main Code.gs serverside.
    }

    function closeMe() {
      google.script.host.close();
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: How would I modify what I have currently in Code.gs format to accomplish this using the htmlOutput?